# Typo3 BackEnd User Log In Programmatically

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-9.x

I have typo3 9.5.

How can i log in a back-end user in typo3 programmatically?

I tried

```
$GLOBALS['BE_USER'] = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\BackendUserAuthentication');

$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->user['uid']=2;

$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->start();
```

But it not work.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more, on your goal. From where do you want that BE user to be logged in? In a FE request? etc.

Comment: From a FE request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$GLOBALS['BE_USER'] = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\BackendUserAuthentication');
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->start();
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->setBeUserByUid(2);
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->createUserSession($GLOBALS['BE_USER']->user);
$url = GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_URL') . TYPO3_mainDir;
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\HttpUtility::redirect($url);
```